# Dockerize java project

Tags: java, maven, docker, vert.x

I have a maven project using vert.x. I deploy all the verticles in a Main class like this:

```
package launcher;

import io.vertx.core.Vertx;

public class MainLauncher {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx();
        vertx.deployVerticle(new ImportFileVerticle());
        vertx.deployVerticle(new InsertFileVerticle()); 
        vertx.deployVerticle(new ExportFileVerticle());
    }

}
```

I added the Dockerfile like this:

```
FROM maven:3.3.9-jdk-8

RUN mkdir -p /opt/app
WORKDIR /opt/app

COPY pom.xml /opt/app/pom.xml
RUN mvn install
COPY . /opt/app/
RUN mvn package

EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["mvn", "exec:java"]
```

I added this dependency in my pom.xml :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I build the image with this command :

> docker build -t  myapp .

And I'm running with this command :

> docker run -p 8080:8080 -t -i myapp

The problem once the running is done, and that I type :

> http://localhost:8080/

nothing happens.

Or by using postman to call the url (localhost: 8081 / listImport) of my verticle to see the list of my imports, nothing happens as.

> Note : ImportFileVerticle listen on 8081, InsertFileVerticle listen on
>   8082, ExportFileVerticle listen on 8083

How can I call the urls defined in these verticles once the docker image has started ?

My 2nd question, I have a docker image containing the frontend of my application, how can I communicate the image containing the frontend with the image contaning the backend and the image containing mysql ?

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

A little bit on how we run our docker containers:

What we do for our image creation is to create an shadow jar will all the dependencies and then we use that executable jar in the docker image. To this we use `io.vertx.core.Launcher` as our main class and then we create an initialization verticle to pull both our configurations and secrets and then spawn all other verticles that we need to run via `vertx.deployVerticle(CLASS);`

Alternately if you don't want to do all this work you can use [Vert-Docker](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-docker/)

Now to answer your question:

1. `-p 8080:8080` this section of your docker run command states that you are port binding 8080 host to 8080 in the docker container.  You state above that you are running your verticles in the container on ports 8081, 8082, 8083.  If you want to access them from the host you have to bind the ports to the host machine.
2. There are two approaches to this:

   - Binding the containers port to the host machine via the `-p` port mapping and setting up the other containers to connect to the host ip address and designated port. ***Please note you cannot use localhost because localhost refers to the containers localhost not host.***
   - Container linking.  You could also use `--link` to create a virtual network and then link the containers that way which will create dns entries in the containers /etc/hosts file that would then put in your configuration for your services. In this case I usually use docker-compose if I'm on the same machine designating dependent containers using the `depends_on` clause. [docker-compose depends_on](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#depends_on)

Hopefully this helps!